# How to have a C# program continue while waiting for data?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am looking to create a program that will create a socket and accept a connection.  If data is received it will parse it and send it to another device.

The kicker is that I don't want the program to 'wait' for data on the socket.  I want to be able to sit in a loop and check if data is received.  If no data is received continue doing other stuff.

I have read about asynchronous sockets but that seems like it is more for having multiple connections.

Is that the right direction that I should be going?  Or should I be looking for something different?

e.g.

```
Main()
{

while (true) {
If new data on socket then
    function1()

function2()

   }
}
```

Thanks for any help and/or advice :)

Comment: Look into `BackgroundWorker`s.  They are a nice way to spawn another thread.

Comment: ...and in case it isn't obvious, threads run independently and your main program won't have to wait while it's doing its thing.

Comment: `Is that the right direction that I should be going?` YES

Comment: IMHO, the best way to use a `Socket` is asynchronously. You can use the `Socket` classes own `Begin/EndXXX` pattern, or its `XXXAsync` pattern (which is _not_ the new `Task`-based async pattern you'll see elsewhere in .NET), or (the best choice for GUI programs) step up an abstraction level and use `TcpClient`, `TcpListener`, or `UdpClient` (depending on the specific needs), where you can get a `NetworkStream` which provides the new-style `Task` based API, usable with C#'s async/await feature.